# How to retrieve the value of an attribute using Seleium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

---

[image]The `HTML` code is given attached, I do not want to use hard code `xpath`, the requirement is to make it generic:

```
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <input name="hotel_name_0" id="hotel_name_0" type="text" value="Hotel Creek" class="select_text" onfocus="disable_ctrlV()" onkeypress="return Nothingonly(event)">
</td>
```

Code:

```
public static boolean fncVerifyTextInColumn(WebElement gridObjWebElement,
            String stringToValidate, int columnNumber,String colName) {
        boolean flagTextinColumn=false;
        ArrayList<WebElement> objRows;
        ArrayList<WebElement> objCols;
        ArrayList<WebElement> childElement;
        objRows=(ArrayList<WebElement>)gridObjWebElement.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        objCols=(ArrayList<WebElement>)objRows.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        if(objCols.get(columnNumber).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(colName)){
            for(int index=1;index<objRows.size();index++){
                objCols=(ArrayList<WebElement>)objRows.get(index).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
                childElement=(ArrayList<WebElement>)objCols.get(columnNumber).findElements(By.xpath("//input"));
                System.out.println(childElement.get(0).getAttribute("value"));
                if(stringToValidate.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(childElement.get(0).getAttribute("value").trim())){
                    flagTextinColumn=true;
                }
            }
        }
        return flagTextinColumn;
    }
```

Method Calling:

```
fncVerifyTextInColumn(objGrid,hotels,1,"Hotel Name");
```

Comment: You want to get `Hotel Creek`?

Comment: yes Saifur, the requirement is to validate this text, which is dynamic.

Comment: The `id="hotel_name_0"` is also dynamic?

Comment: added snapshot of html code

Comment: @Saifur, it is also dynamic

Comment: Is that a public site? Can you provide me the `url`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71307/discussion-between-saifur-and-prateeksethi).

Comment: hi prateek , the td you have mentioned would have a <tr> right is that <tr> has some unique value ? id yes so we can count the the number of <td> in that tr and we can put condition if ( name = hotel_name ) getAttribute("value"); ... if you want i can write code for you.

Comment: @PrateekSethi You are doing a lot of work than you are needed.

Comment: @Himanshu, as attached image, I could not see tr for unique values

Comment: can you try with `//input[contains(@id,'hotel_name')][@value='Hotel Name']`

Answer (score 2):

I would use cssSelector `[id^='hotel_name_']` to locate the element and then `getAttribute()` retrieve the attribute value

```
By css = By.cssSelector("[id^='hotel_name_']");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(css));
System.out.println(myDynamicElement.getAttribute("value"));
```

Notice the `regex` search of `cssSelector` here. With `^` I am skipping any dynamic number. Hoping that's the only element with `hotel_name_someNumber` on the page.

Comment: Thanks Saifur, but there could be more than one row based on user search criteria.

Comment: Provide me more html or url to the site so I can write you a unique selector

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
String attValue = driver.findElement(byAnyMethod).getAttribute("AttributeName");
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this.  (I'm assuming you know how to code, you just need a general direction so I'm going to leave out specific code.)

First, find the table the td is in.  You might need to use an xPath for this or you'll need to assign an ID to the table so you can locate it.

Then once you have the table, do a FindElements to get the list of TRs under it.

Once you have the TRs, you can loop through them, grab the TDs under that and grab the TD at the index that has the INPUT you want the value of, get the INPUT and then get it's value.

Yep, lots of steps.

A shortcut may be to class all of the inputs you want the value for with a unique class and do a FindElements By className and loop through that list.